# How to pass order by field name to slect query which in inside a cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How to pass order by column names dynamically in cursor select query, those field name values comes as procedure inputs.

Declared a local variable and tried to append to select query in the a cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE biq_security_report (
    out_chr_err_code   OUT                VARCHAR2,
    out_chr_err_msg    OUT                VARCHAR2,
    out_security_tab   OUT                return_security_arr_result,
    in_sort_column     IN                 VARCHAR2,
    in_order_by        IN                 VARCHAR2
) IS

    l_chr_srcstage        VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_biqtab          VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_srctab          VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_bistagtab       VARCHAR2(200);
    l_chr_err_code        VARCHAR2(255);
    l_chr_err_msg         VARCHAR2(255);
    l_out_chr_errbuf      VARCHAR2(2000);
    lrec                  return_security_report;
    CURSOR cur_security_data IS
    SELECT
        "ID"     "requestId",
        "ROOM"   "room"
    FROM
        "BI_REQUEST_CATERING_ACTIVITY"
    WHERE
        id > 2000
        AND room < 400
    ORDER BY
        in_sort_column ASC;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('HERE INSIIDE OTHERS' || sqlerrm);
END;
```

in cursor select query we need pass values through the procedure call.

Comment: _columns_, not _fields_...

Answer (score 0):

You can try following the logic:

```
SELECT
    "ID"     "requestId",
    "ROOM"   "room"
FROM
    "BI_REQUEST_CATERING_ACTIVITY"
WHERE
    ID > 2000
    AND ROOM < 400
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN UPPER(IN_ORDER_BY) = 'DESC'
             AND IN_SORT_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN IN_SORT_COLUMN 
    END DESC,
    CASE
        WHEN IN_SORT_COLUMN IS NOT NULL THEN IN_SORT_COLUMN 
    END;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

`in_sort_column` is a string literal and if you sort by it then it is going to be constant for every row. Instead you need to map the string literal you are inputting to a column and this can be done in a `CASE` statement where you whitelist the column names:

```sql
CURSOR cur_security_data IS
SELECT ID   AS requestId,
       ROOM
FROM   BI_REQUEST_CATERING_ACTIVITY
WHERE  id   > 2000
AND    room < 400
ORDER BY
    CASE in_sort_column
    WHEN 'ID'      THEN id
    WHEN 'ROOM'    THEN room
    WHEN 'COLUMN1' THEN column1
    WHEN 'COLUMN2' THEN column2
    ELSE                column3 -- default column to sort by
    END ASC;
```

*(Note: Don't double quote identifiers unless there is a real business case where it is appropriate. Double-quotes enforces case-sensitivity in the identifier which means you have to use the exact combination of upper and lower case characters every time you refer to the identifier. Instead, just leave the identifiers unquoted and let Oracle manage the case-sensitivity and future developers will have a much easier time with the code.)*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a separate `case` expression for each column:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN in_sort_column = 'id' THEN id END),
         (CASE WHEN in_sort_column = 'room' THEN room END),
         . . .
```

The `ASC` is optional, because that is the default ordering.

Why use separate `CASE` expressions?  Simple.  A `CASE` expression returns a single value, with a single type.  You don't want the `CASE` to start converting values to unexpected types -- creating either conversion errors or unexpected ordering.

EDIT:

To handle both ascending and descending sorts:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN in_sort_column = 'id' AND in_order_by = 'ASC' THEN id END) ASC,
         (CASE WHEN in_sort_column = 'id' AND in_order_by = 'DESC' THEN id END) DESC,
         . . .
```

Comment: but if the user needs to sort DESC order.?